# Does Nokia X allow ADB over network?

Tags: adb, nokiax

Due to space limitations in my office, I'd like to deploy my apps via network instead of via usb. Both the phone and the PC are in the same network.

I'm hoping for something similar to Ouya: a checkbox in the settings and then "adb connect "

Comment: Gotta admit that I'm not 100% certain I understand the issues here, but I would assume that if the thing that you are looking for does work on AOSP based devices having API level 16 stuff in them, then it should indeed work on Nokia X. Or is there some additional requirements that would also be needed to be met ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect with USB cable and run:

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

Disconnect USB cable and run:

```
adb connect 192.168.0.100:5555
```

Change the IP to the actual IP of the device.